# Service start and Permission denied

Tags: centos, permissions, services

I have a script that execute a java program, and I want to create a service to start this script at boot time.

So I've created a script called run.sh.

**/test/run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp myjar:/test/lib/* com.xxxx.util.AmazonS3FileDownloader
```

I have also created a file called `test` in `/etc/init.d`

**/etc/init.d/test**

```
#!/bin/bash
/test/run.sh
```

For testing purposes I gave the test folder `/test` all rights (chmod 777 /test).

```
drwxrwxrwx    7 testuser testuser  4096 Dec 12 13:28 test
```

And this is what inside `/etc/ini.d` folder

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2062 Dec 12 13:18 test
```

If I run this command. Everything is fine. No error, the program is running fine.

```
$ /test/run.sh
```

but for a reason I ignore if I try to do the same thing but using the service. It doesn;t work.

```
$ service test start
```

I've got permission denied when creating the `receipts_download.log` in `/test` folder.

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: receipts_download.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:97)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:689)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:118)
    at com.xxxxx.util.AmazonS3FileDownloader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxxxx.util.AmazonS3FileDownloader.main(Unknown Source)
```

`/test` has all permission and why I can run `$ /test/run.sh` without problem but not `$ service test start`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it hard-coded in the script to create the file in '/test' directory? Or the script is creating the file at `cwd` ? If the script is creating the file at `cwd`, then you have to `cd /test` before running the script.

Comment: @Sree instead of doing /test/run.sh in the test script, I did cd /test and then ./run.sh and it seems to work fine. Thanks a lot. If you want you response accepted you can write one and I will accept it ;)

Comment: re-wrote it in the answer section. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the script is creating the 'receipts_download.log' file in the `cwd` and your `cwd` when running the script is not `/test`. Please `cd /test` before running the script and it will go okay.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is most likely in environment variables and current working directory. `service` starts script from `/` and with clean environment. So, you may need to examine your environment and current working directory (with the help of `export`, `pwd` or `set` commands) and add missing prerequisites into your script.